# Get column value of every record in listview

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, listview

I am trying to retrieve a certain column value for every record in a listview. So basically my column name is `UnitID` and if I have 6 records in that listview I want the value for UnitID for every record. I have don't really know where to start with this. All I can find online is examples where the user has a selected column and is getting the value from that selected row.

Comment: Can you just query the same datasource that you are using to bind the listview to?

Comment: That is currently what I am trying. I am trying to get the info from the SQL server, instead of going about getting the data from the listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a workaround to solve this problem. What I did was used a stored procedure to get the values I needed, then gathered it through the code behind. This work around makes it so you do not need to retrieve values from the ListView

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you get values as you read them from the data source and store them in an array or get values from list view with a for loop? Would be much simpler than using a stored procedure.